# ClamAV - What does the "clamd@scan" service do by default?

Tags: malware, clamav

I have been researching ClamAV to understand what the "clamd@scan" service does by default in case of finding threats. So far I have not been able to get a satisfactory and clear answer (forums, documentations, etc)...

---

**QUESTION:** What does the "clamav@scan" service do by default if it finds threats?

---

**FURTHER QUESTION:** I would like ClamAV to have the "classic" behavior of an antivirus engine, that is, remove threats automatically. If he doesn't do this by default what should I do to make him do it?

**NOTE:** The operating system of choice was CentOS 7 and the process used is described in this tutorial https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-clamav-on-centos-7/ .

**Thanks! =D**

Comment: As to the 'further question', it should be noted that back in 2016, this was written: https://blog.clamav.net/2016/03/configuring-on-access-scanning-in-clamav.html
Basically you need the `ScanOnAccess` option configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> QUESTION: What does the "clamav@scan" service do by default if it finds threats?

It informs the client

> FURTHER QUESTION: I would like ClamAV to have the "classic" behavior of an antivirus engine, that is, remove threats automatically.

it doesn't do that. it just sits around waiting for something to give it a file to inspect.

> If he doesn't do this by default what should I do to make him do it?

use the "clamscan" command.

Answer (score 3):

**I thought it would be useful to post here some answers obtained in one of the official email lists of ClamAV** ( clamav-users@lists.clamav.net, https://www.clamav.net/contact ). In my view, **they give a good view of how to proceed taking into account the questions that I made**.

---

**Orion's Answers:**

- QUESTION

> I have been researching ClamAV to understand what the "clamd@scan"
>   service does by default in case of finding threats. So far I have not
>   been able to get a satisfactory and clear answer (forums,
>   documentations, etc)...
>
> QUESTION: What does the "clamav@scan" service do by default if it
>   finds threats?

- ANSWER

> The clamd@scan service runs clamd with the configuration file
>   "/etc/clamd.d/scan.conf". See that file for details.

- QUESTION

> FURTHER QUESTION: I would like ClamAV to have the "classic" behavior
>   of an antivirus engine, that is, remove threats automatically. If he
>   doesn't do this by default what should I do to make him do it?

- ANSWER

> Consult "man clamd.conf" and the comments in "/etc/clamd.d/scan.conf"
>   for your options.

---

**G.W.'s Answers:**

- QUESTION

> QUESTION: What does the "clamav@scan" service do by default if it
>   finds threats?

- ANSWER

> I do not know exactly which package you are using. The behaviour of
>   the service provided by a package will depend on how it was configured
>   by the package provider. Assuming the package maintainer has not lost
>   his sanity, the service will be configured simply to report findings
>   (for example by logging a message to a system log and, if you use a
>   command-line tool, printing a message on the tty/terminal/whatever).
>
> Read the documentation on the ClamAV Website for more information:
>
> http://www.clamav.net/documents/clam-antivirus-user-manual
>
> Copies and parodies of ClamAV documentation elsewhere on the Internet
>   can be out of date, misleading, sometimes incorrect, and occasionally
>   downright dangerous.

- QUESTION

> FURTHER QUESTION: I would like ClamAV to have the "classic" behavior
>   of an antivirus engine, that is, remove threats automatically. If he
>   doesn't do this by default what should I do to make him do it?

- ANSWER

> Read the part which says
>
> "Be careful!"
>
> If you have not yet found that part, keep reading until you do.

- QUESTION

> NOTES:  I - The operating system of choice was CentOS 7 and the
>   process used is described in this tutorial
>   https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-clamav-on-centos-7/

- ANSWER

> Generally speaking I recommend that you avoid tutorials like this
>   because they tend to make decisions for you without the benefit of
>   information about your situation which only you can have. I recommend
>   that you do NOT attempt to automate threat removal on any Linux system
>   without very careful consideration. Careless use of ClamAV on a Linux
>   system will do more harm than good. In particular, this tutorial will
>   have you scan locations in the filesystem which can not safely be
>   scanned with ClamAV, nor with any anti-virus tool. Keep in mind that,
>   even in a minimal installation, ClamAV scans for much more than just
>   viruses and malware and that the false positive rate is never zero. I
>   feel that you do not at present understand the issues well enough to
>   consider them sufficiently carefully.
>
> I have been using ClamAV for many years, on hundreds of Linux systems.
>   Perhaps this is mainly because of good hygiene but I have not yet seen
>   ClamAV find a Linux virus, nor Linux malware, nor Linux rootkit on any
>   Linux system. I should be pleased if anyone who has will report, here
>   on this list, what they have found, when they found it, and how they
>   think it got there. Any Linux system which has been compromised is a
>   danger, and my advice would be to rebuild it from scratch.